# Sqlite and air Boolean object example

Tags: sqlite, air

I am using Adobe Air and Sqlite for storing user data and I want to use Boolean value with a `Checkbox` and store the data in the DB but I don't know how to do it. I know that I have to use INTEGER and store in it values 0 or 1 but how I do it?!

And I couldn't how any example on the net.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) link,

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

So Create the table with the specified column as `INTEGER`, and insert the value as it is. SQLite should automatically convert them into 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

AIR's version of SQLite has been modified to include ten additional column affinity types, and one of those types is Boolean. So if a database column named, for example, *inStock* has been declared as a Boolean, a query like this would work:

```
SELECT titleID FROM main.Books WHERE inStock = true;
```